# Tag [Aerobic] is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-cleanup, retagging

I think we should make the ambiguous tag [aerobic](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aerobic) more clear as it might be used for

- **aerobics** describing [the sport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerobics).
- **aerobic-exercise** describing all exercises [also known as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerobic_exercise) [cardio](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardio)

The last point suggest a synonym, I lack the reputation on that tag to put it into effect. I'd suggest that *aerobic* is renamed to *cardio*, as there are far more questions tagged with *cardio*. (16 to 108)
There is currently [one question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/11994/3941) where I think *aerobics* could be meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a synonym, so when someone types aerobic (as in aerobic exercise), it'll get changed to cardio.

While I bet there are semantic differences between the two terms, I think you're right that its a lot clearer and won't cause confusion with aerobics.